# Copy Sheet and Update Active X Combo Box

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook, which includes a data entry form that will copy data from the input sheet to specific sheets based off the Active X Combo Box which includes all the sheet names. I have given the user the ability to add a new page, which copies a template page and sorts all the pages alphabetically. However, the worksheet. Activate which is where the code is stored to populate the Active X Combo Box with all the sheet name does not populate. Also, every couple times testing this code it doesn't name the sheet properly, renaming it Template (2) and places it at the end, however sometimes it correctly names the sheet and places it properly. I am not sure why the code doesn't always work as expected and the combo box is not populating by the worksheet.activate event. Could you please help me, please see the code below.

```vb
Private Sub cbAddPlant_Click()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ShCount As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ShCount = Sheets.Count
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    If tbPlantName.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please Enter A Plant Name!", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    Else
        wb.Worksheets("Template").Copy Before:=wb.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = tbPlantName
    End If
    
    For i = 2 To ShCount - 1
        For j = i + 1 To ShCount
            If UCase(Sheets(j).Name) < UCase(Sheets(i).Name) Then
                Sheets(j).Move Before:=Sheets(i)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
    wb.Worksheets("Input").cbPlantName.Clear
    For i = 2 To ShCount - 1
        wb.Worksheets("Input").cbPlantName.AddItem Sheets(i).Name
    Next
    
    Wb.Worksheets("Input").Activate
    Unload AddPlant
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I think this might be a safer way to reference the copied sheet `wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count - 1).Name = tbPlantName`   If you have a `sheetactivate` event in all your sheets then moving it to the ThisWorkbook module (as `Workbook_SheetActivate`) might make things more manageable.  Note also you mix and match `worksheets` and `sheets` - they're not exactly the same, since `sheets` also includes chart sheets for example.   Not a problem if all you have is worksheets, but keep in mind if you ever add a chart then you might run into problems.

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks so much for your help. When I replace ActiveSheet.Name = tbPlantName with wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count - 1).Name = tbPlantName, it's creating a template sheet in a new workbook. Thanks for the sheet comment, that's very helpful. Do you think the improper reference to the copied sheet makes it fail sometimes?

Comment: I think that  the code problem may be `wb.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)`.  `Worksheets.Count` refers the active workbook. If it happens to not have `ThisWorkbook` activated, the copied sheet will be placed according to the active workbook number of worksheets. So, it is good to be fully qualified, too:  `wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count)`. But this will only wrongly place the copied sheet. Since it will become the active one, its name should be correctly allocated by your code...

Comment: "it's creating a template sheet in a new workbook" - if that's happening then you didn't specify a destination in `wb.Worksheets("Template").Copy`